# How to identify a pure UIView subview out of various Custom View subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am parsing through the subviews of a parent view,
It has various subviews, all custom classes, of 10 different UIView subclasses.
There is just one class which is a normal UIView.

Now when I am looping thru, I need to get hold of the UIView subview, isKindOfClass is failing to do so as it returns 1 for all the UIView subclasses as well.

Do I have to write a a big if-else construct to check if its an object of any other custom UIView subclass and then in the last else come to a conclusion that its a normal UIView.

Or is there a method that tells me exact class of the view ?

Comment: What is the reason of a) not using standard or custom `tag` property b) not storing the added `UIView` subview at internal variable (wrapped with the getter method) for the fastest access ?

Comment: You should use isMemberOfClass instead

Comment: Its a bug, I was solving in someone else's mess :)
There are various custom view created randomly at runtime...and emoved.. its just one set of views that was UIView with all the customization done with outside of it. like labels and all.

Others were custom views. I was just writing some quick and dirty hack to get the mess work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud use :

```
[currentView isMemberOfClass:[UIView class]];
```

Answer (score -1):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isMemberOfClass:

Comment: Can you provide some context here? What is the relevance of this link?